# ATLAS on a python virtualenv in Fedora for numpy/scipy/scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, virtualenv, blas, atlas

I am struggeling to let python find and use the installed ATLAS libraries from my distribution when using virtualenv.

This is on Fedora 21, atlas, atlas-devel, blas, blas-devel are installed. Outside of a virtualenv, the command `python -c 'import numpy; numpy.show_config()'` shows that I have ATLAS:

```
atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    libraries = ['tatlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.10.1\\""')]
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['tatlas', 'tatlas', 'tatlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas']
    define_macros = [('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.10.1\\""')]
    language = f77
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['tatlas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib64/atlas']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('ATLAS_INFO', '"\\"3.10.1\\""')]
    language = c
    include_dirs = ['/usr/include']
openblas_info:
NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
NOT AVAILABLE
[...]
```

And `ls /usr/lib64/atlas/` gives:

```
libatlas.a   libsatlas.so    libsatlas.so.3.10  libtatlas.so.3
libcblas.so  libsatlas.so.3  libtatlas.so       libtatlas.so.3.10
```

I also setup an environment variable, so that `echo $ATLAS` gives

```
/usr/lib64/atlas/libsatlas.so
```

But when I do the following:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
pip install scikit-learn
python -c 'import numpy; numpy.show_config()'
```

I get:

```
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    language = c
blas_mkl_info:
NOT AVAILABLE
```

I would really appreciate help with how to get numpy and scipy simply find and use ATLAS from my distribution in a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell numpy's setup.py where to find your ATLAS libraries.

Try creating a `.numpy-site.cfg` file in your home folder before running `pip install`. [Here's](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/site.cfg.example) the template for this file.

You probably need to add the lines

```
[atlas]
library_dirs = /usr/lib64/atlas
include_dirs = /usr/include
```

Although, this has required a little bit of trial-and-error in my experience.

Using this file in conjunction with `pip install` seems to work reliably on RHEL and Ubuntu, at least within virtual environments where you don't need `sudo`.

If this fails for one or more of numpy, scipy and scikit-learn, consider installing from source instead, and modify the site.cfg file inside the source dir before running `python setup.py install`.

Comment: So far still no resolution, I tried ``library_dirs = /usr/lib64/atlas`` and ``include_dirs = /usr/include:/usr/include/atlas-x86_64-base`` under ``[atlas]``. Looks like I might have to compile from source as you mentioned if more fiddling with the folders will not help.